# PowerShell: Escape characters in Replace and Contains operations

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to replace all occurrences of `$(foo)\bar` with `$(foo)\baz\bar` literal string, I don't need to expand anything and I don't need to use regex.

This is my code:

```
if($myString.contains("$(foo)\bar\"))
{
    $myString = $myString -replace "$(foo)\bar\","$(foo)\baz\bar\"
    ...
}
```

It doesn't work, I'm totally lost how, when and where to escape characters like `$`, `(`, `\` . Should I use single or double quotes in strings?

This is my attempt:

```
if($myString.contains("`$(foo)\\bar\\"))
{
    $myString = $myString -replace '\$(foo)\\bar\\','\$(foo)\\baz\\bar\\'
    ...
}
```

Comment: `$myString = $myString.Replace('$(foo)\bar\', '$(foo)\baz\bar\')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-replace` command always works with regex. You could either escape the string correctly or just use the `.replace`-method of the string object. The method does not use regex, so no escaping is needed:

```
if($myString.contains("`$(foo)\\bar\\"))
{
$myString = $myString.replace( '$(foo)\bar\','$(foo)\baz\bar\')
...
}
```